# customizing docker bridge network

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-container, docker-network

I want my docker0 and all containers to have the same gateway address or be in the same IPrange as my local machine. I started by defining a fixed-cidr in ther daemon.json file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "bip": "10.80.44.248/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "10.80.44.250/25",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "10.80.44.254",
  "dns": ["10.80.41.14"]
}
```

It seems to be working looking at the output of the `ip -a`
It seems the docker0 has never received any data since.

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet *10.80.44.248*  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast *10.80.44.255*
        ether 02:42:9c:b9:e1:63  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet *10.80.44.39*  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast *10.80.44.255*
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb1:79e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:b1:79:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 211061  bytes 30426474 (29.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 33861  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3032  bytes 260143 (254.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The local machine and the docker0 are in same IP range with the same gateway. Good.
But when I start the docker containers and inspected the bridge settings Everything was different. This is the output of

```
docker network inspect bridge


[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "b326a37a589245449e1268bbb9ee65262eb7986574c0e972c56d350aa82d7238",
        "Created": "2018-04-04T03:25:52.00544539+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.80.44.248/24",
                    "IPRange": "10.80.44.128/25",
                    "Gateway": "10.80.44.248",
                    "AuxiliaryAddresses": {
                        "DefaultGatewayIPv4": "10.80.44.254"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I don't understand why now IPAM config is having a IPv4 als auxiliary

"AuxiliaryAddresses": {
                        "DefaultGatewayIPv4": "10.80.44.254"
                    }

I realised that now the bridge is not created from the same subnet as it was configured by the `daemon` I it created 2 different bridges with different IP ranges. That is still the default from docker.

> docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
b326a37a5892        bridge                 bridge              local
6ce11066cdea        dockergitlab_default   bridge              local
d5a36c04b809        host                   host                local
15f66b88ee67        none                   null                local
```

> docker network inspect dockergitlab_default

```
[
    {
        "Name": "dockergitlab_default",
        "Id": "6ce11066cdeabf3cfe65b2dff22046bd1e9c18d2588f47b9cd3c52ea24f7a636",
        "Created": "2018-03-14T08:56:23.351051727+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "60f769c91cff1de47794a7c8b587b778488883da094ae32cfde5196ee0f528f1": {
                "Name": "gitlab-runner",
                "EndpointID": "5122fe862537fb8434a484b4797153274b945e20bc3c7223efc6fd0bd55eae14",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9c46e1fde6390142bddf67270cfeda7b3e68b1a6e68cabc334046db687240a8d": {
                "Name": "dockergitlab_postgresql_1",
                "EndpointID": "8488b32cc34a2c92308528de74b5eddcecac12a402ee6e67c1ef0f2750b72721",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "eaf29f5f405cbf9bdd918efad26ceae1a8c3f58f4bef0aa8fd86b4631bcfdf43": {
                "Name": "dockergitlab_gitlab_1",
                "EndpointID": "d7f78ee9bd51dd13826d7834470d03a9084fc7ab8c6567c0181acecc221628c6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f460687ec00eff214fa08adfe9a0af5b85c392ceb470c4ed630ef7ecb0bfcba1": {
                "Name": "dockergitlab_redis_1",
                "EndpointID": "8b18906f1c79a5faaadd32afdef20473f9b635e9a1cd2c7108dd98df48eaed86",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dockergitlab"
        }
    }
]
```

I have no idea why the docker bridge is now created with the old default ip address.

> LOCAL SYSTEM Details

I can do `apt update` on the local machine but when i logged into the gitlab-runner i can't do `apt update`

```
Linux  4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64

Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
```

Is there a way I can oveeride the bridge settings. From what i have read, when I define/configure the cdir and gateway in daemon.json file everything will be taken from there for the creation of the bridge network and all other containers.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you've correctly configured the `docker0` bridge and starting containers with the plain `docker run` command should connect them to the bridge and give them IPs in `10.80.44.250/25`.

From what you've pasted I guess you're using `docker-compose` to start your containers.

> `docker-compose` will create a `myproject_default` network per docker-compose.yml if you don't specify anything.

Today you cannot choose in which pool the IP ranges will be chosen, it's by default a `172.[17-31].0.0/16`. There is currently an active pull request to allow override of this behaviour : https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396.

If you want to manually specify the IP range in your `docker-compose.yml` you can write this :

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.80.44.250/25
```

Edit : this is only compatible with a docker-compose syntax >=3.0.

Comment: awwww thanks. You are right. that is why things are not working. I will try and do it manually in my compose config files. Do I still have to keep  the docker0 config?

Comment: I am getting unsupported config options when I add this network options  to my docker-compose.yml. any tips. I am using file format '2.2' for the docker-compose. Thanks

Comment: I fixed it now. I am still getting overlapping IPv4 address with the docker0. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the subnets shouldn't overlap so you'll have to choose two different ranges for docker0 and your docker-compose network.
So here yo may want to use two consecutive /26 instead of your /25 : one for docker0 and one for dockergitlab_default.

Comment: Thanks man. I will give it a shot. The problem is want the docker container to have the same default gateway "default-gateway": "10.80.44.254" and if different subnets for each I don't think it will be possible

Comment: If you want the containers you start manually to run in the same network as the one in your docker-compose you can specify the network with `--net dockergitlab_default`.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Yes I will love that the containers be in the same subnet as the docker0 and have the same "default-gateway": "10.80.44.254". Should I specify this option on ``docker-compose up -d``

Comment: I was suggesting starting the containers in the docker-compose network and connecting plain `docker run` containers to this network. If you run docker-compose containers in the default bridge (`docker0`) you will loose automatic DNS resolution between containers (what you got when you use `links` in docker-compose.yml). You can check the docs here : https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: Yea containers connected to the default bridge communicate using IP address right? I just to make sure that the gateway is  10.80.44.254 so that my gitlab-runner can do ``sudo apt update``. I don't fully understand your solution yet. What do you mean plan docker containers? I have four containers in the compose.yml. Should I run them in the default bridge and after that connect them to the Docker0? Is there a way to have the docker0 and the default have the same gatewy address? Thanks. I tried doing it manually but getting conflicts.

Comment: I meant if you want to run containers outside docker-compose.yml. If you only want to use docker-compose just split your pool in two (docker0 and dockercompose_default) and don't mind what I said earlier : it will just work and you don't need to do anything with the `docker0` interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168231/discussion-between-hugoshaka-and-seek-addo).